# Proxy Error when I update my application on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Ruby on Rails application hosted on Amazon with Elastic BeanStalk. When I do an update and I do some change to run my application I have, on the website's page, this error :

> Proxy Error
>
> The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
>   The proxy server could not handle the request GET
>   http://commentmyprojects-env-vpusz2adwc.elasticbeanstalk.com/.
>
> Reason: Error reading from remote server
>
> Apache Server at commentmyprojects-env-vpusz2adwc.elasticbeanstalk.com
>   Port 3128

When I restart the application, through the Beanstalk's console, over and over it works after a while.

How can I do to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: No, I update my application with `git aws.push`.

Comment: same problem here with Java/Tomcat... did you solve?

Comment: I think it was due to an instable internet connection